# Horizontal scroll and focus on the last number in a TextView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, textview

I am doing a calculator app.

I have a TextView where the user writes the numbers to elaborate.

The TextView is inside a HorizontalScrollView. The HorizontalScrollView is inside a vertical LinearLayout. The TextView is single line, and, when the user writes a long number, the number comes out of the screen.

The TextView should follow the last number added by the user, so he can view the last numbers added without scrolling the screen. I don't want an autoscroll function that repeat the scroll every second, i only want focus on the last number added.

This is the TextView

```
<HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/numberDisplay"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:hint="0"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:textSize="70sp" />

        </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1. In your activity create variables for your scroll view and text view:

   ```
   TextView textView;
   HorizontalScrollView scrollView;
   ```
2. Initialize them in `onCreate()`:

   ```
   scrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView); // Add this id to xml
   textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numberDisplay);
   ```
3. Each time you update text of your text view update scroll position of the scroll view:

   ```
   scrollView.scrollTo(textView.getRight(), textView.getTop());
   ```

**Update:**
I realized that if you call `textView.setText(...)` and then immediately `scrollView.scrollTo(...)` it does not work since text view size is not updated immediately. You should rather update scoll position like this:

```
    scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            scrollView.scrollTo(textView.getRight(), textView.getTop());
        }
    });
```